# Is it possible to match multiple keys of a Map instead of IF statements inside forEach?

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to filter a Map and extract values by matching keys to strings. The map is  and values can either be string or List. Following is the code snippet-

```
container.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (("userId").equals(k))
                registerContainer.setUserId(v.toString());
            if (("languageId").equals(k))
                registerContainer.setUserLanguage(v.toString());

            if (("formDetails").equals(k)) {

                registerContainer.setFields((ArrayList) v);
            }

            if (("value1").equals(k)) {
                HashMap fieldEntry = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                fieldEntry.put("fieldKey", k);
                fieldEntry.put("fieldValue", v.toString());
                masterParams.add(fieldEntry);
            }
            if (("value2").equals(k)) {
                HashMap fieldEntry = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                fieldEntry.put("fieldKey", k);
                fieldEntry.put("fieldValue", v.toString());
                masterParams.add(fieldEntry);
            }


                if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(params)) {

                    registerContainer.setFields(masterParams);
                }

        });
```

My question is, is there a way to eliminate all the if statements and still be able to have the desired outcome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do exactly the same for `("value1").equals(k)` and `("value2").equals(k)`, you can use a single `if("value1".equals(k) || "value2".equals(k)) { … }`. Besides that, it looks like `if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(params)) { registerContainer.setFields(masterParams); }` should not be done for every element but a single time *after* the `forEach` operation. And `params` ought to be `masterParams`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by using the `switch` statement and squash code for `value1` and `value2` as both do the same things.
So sth like this:

```
container.forEach((k, v) -> {
            switch(k){
                case "userId":
                    registerContainer.setUserId(v.toString());
                    break;
                case "languageId":
                    registerContainer.setUserLanguage(v.toString());
                    break;
                case "formDetails":
                    registerContainer.setFields((ArrayList) v);
                    break;
                case "value1":
                case "value2":    
                    HashMap fieldEntry = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                    fieldEntry.put("fieldKey", k);
                    fieldEntry.put("fieldValue", v.toString());
                    masterParams.add(fieldEntry);
                    break;
            }
        });
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(params)) {
    registerContainer.setFields(masterParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Java 8:

```
   container.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("value1")).findFirst()
                .ifPresent(e -> {
                    System.out.println(e.getValue()); 
                });
```